# FizzBuzz in Dlang

Tags: d, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to get fizzbuzz working in D but I have no idea for the life of me what the problem is. I have tried reversing the logic and it does write both words when it is not appropriate, but when it is it just writes nothing.

Here's a screenshot of what the output looks like: http://puu.sh/p67Hd/2a5a598b1b.png

```d
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    for (uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i%5 && i%3) write(i);
        if (!i%3) write("Fizz");
        if (!i%5) write("Buzz");
        writeln();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz#D

Comment: I'm no `D` guy but I'd guess `!` is binding more closely than `%`; add some parentheses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `!` operator has precedence over `%` so your `if` statements look like

```d
if ((!i) % 3) write("Fizz");
if ((!i) % 5) write("Buzz");
```

and because all of `i` is non-zero (besides the first time), `!i` is always `0` and `0 % 5` and `0 % 3` is always `0 (false)`.

To fix, all you need to do is add parenthesis around the `%` operations

```d
if (!(i % 3)) write("Fizz");
if (!(i % 5)) write("Buzz");
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the [operator precedence in D](http://wiki.dlang.org/Operator_precedence).

The `if(!i%3)` will actually be interpreted as `if((!i)%3)`, which results in either 0%3 (which is false), or 1%3 (which is true). `!n` will result in 1 if n is 0, otherwise it will always be 0. Because it's going from 0 to 100, `(!i) % 3` will only be true once at the beginning. This is the reason why there is a FizzBuzz at the start of the output.

So instead your code should look like this:

```d
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    for (uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i%5 && i%3) write(i);
        if (!(i%3)) write("Fizz");
        if (!(i%5)) write("Buzz");
        writeln();
    }
}
```